# imageio: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imread'

Tags: python, imread, python-imageio

I come up with the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imread'` while using the `imageio` module with the following code. I searched the community a lot but all of the errors about `imread` command are discussed under `scipy`, but nothing for `imageio`. So, any comments or links are appreciated! Here is my code:

```
import os
import imageio

os.chdir('C:/concent')

png_dir='gif/'

images=[]

for file_name in os.listdir(png_dir):
    if file_name.endswith('.png'):
        file_path = os.path.join(png_dir, file_name)
        images.append(imageio.imread(file_path))
imageio.mimsave('gif/movie.gif', images)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have another file named `imageio.py` in the working directory.

The `import` statement will import files from the current directory before searching standard library and site package locations.

You should be able to fix the problem by renaming your local `imageio.py` file to something else that does not clash with other modules.

Comment: Run from the terminal a pop up requests permission.